# What is this strange setTimeout syntax?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I ran across code like the following (that actually works) and am curious what is happening with the syntax.

```
function timeout(a){
  alert(a);
}

setTimeout('timeout(5)', 2000); //alerts 5 after two seconds
```

I have seen pointers to functions being passed to setTimeout and also anonymous functions. Is passing a function in quotes with parenthesis valid? I could find nothing about it on MDN.

Comment: It's valid, but typically considered a bad practice because it's a form of eval.

Comment: It's valid. It's how you pass a function with a preset parameter value as a callback. Like @KevinB said, though, it's not typically looked highly upon.

Comment: Note: MDN lists this syntax as [`var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

Comment: [See Rule #3 of the Owasp guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Typo corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is passing a function in quotes with parenthesis valid?

Yes, you can pass a string with arbitrary code into `setTimeout`; it doesn't even have to be a function. It's not a good idea. The code is evaluated as though it were at global scope.

The modern way to do that would be:

```
setTimeout(timeout.bind(null, 5), 2000);
```

Comment: What is the danger of it being evaluated "at global scope"?

Comment: @thomas: I mean it doesn't have to be a function. For instance: `setTimeout("location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';", 1000);` will set the `location` to `http://stackoverflow.com` after a second.

Comment: @thomas: There's no *danger* to it being evaluated at global scope, but it tends to surprise people, and it encourages creating global functions (so you can call them this way), which is a bad idea because the global namespace is **very** crowded on browsers.

Answer (score 0):

MDN documentation is confusing.

every one make this mistake : using parenthesis for functions arguments.

but even on MDN syntax is clear:

```
var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(function[, delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

so, like your sample

```
window.setTimeout(timeout, 1000, 'hello');

function timeout(a){
    echo a;
}
```